# Is there a clean way to implement mlultiple if statements of the same type in julia?

Tags: if-statement, julia

Something like this:

```
if mod(i,11) = 1,2,3,4,5...
     #do something
else
     #do something else
end
```

I dont want to type out each condition or make a for loop, I want to keep the syntax as simple as possible.

Comment: are you looking for `if mod(i,11) ∈ [1,2,3,4,5]` ?

Comment: yes thats exaclty what I wanted, thank you.

Comment: if you use it in the loop use `Set` for better performance like this `Set([1, 2, 3])` and preallocate it outside of the loop.

Comment: If you are actually testing for membership in a range, you are better off testing `mod(i, 11) in (1:5)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is the answer to the question

```
if mod(i,11) ∈ [1,2,3,4,5]
```